# 2013 MacBook Pro running on Yosemite crashes when thunderbolt is attached

Tags: display, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

Ever since updating, and also now having a done a clean install, my 15" retina mac book pro crashes every time I plug a thunderbolt connector into it - whether its the thunderbolt diplay, or a monitor, doesn't matter.

As a laptop it great - but I need to be able to hook it up to other display options.

Any ideas? I can't seem to find much on this specific issue. Also, its my first mac, so not sure how to properly diagnose the problem.

EDIT: the most recent crash report*****

```
Anonymous UUID:       A8937A82-52A5-13F3-8F8A-FFC695409640

Thu Nov 27 19:31:52 2014

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f92452f63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x104200000 0xffffff8200028000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P0/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.7.21/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81cf5e5ba0 : 0xffffff800f93a811 
0xffffff81cf5e5c20 : 0xffffff7f92452f63 
0xffffff81cf5e5d00 : 0xffffff7f90499d28 
0xffffff81cf5e5dc0 : 0xffffff7f905641b6 
0xffffff81cf5e5e00 : 0xffffff7f90799acc 
0xffffff81cf5e5e20 : 0xffffff7f904a06fe 
0xffffff81cf5e5ec0 : 0xffffff7f9044f7b0 
0xffffff81cf5e5ee0 : 0xffffff800feda76f 
0xffffff81cf5e5f10 : 0xffffff7f9013f79d 
0xffffff81cf5e5f50 : 0xffffff7f924d7db4 
0xffffff81cf5e5f60 : 0xffffff7f924dfeeb 
0xffffff81cf5e5f80 : 0xffffff800fa1dd25 
0xffffff81cf5e5fd0 : 0xffffff800fa3a609 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f90124000->0xffffff7f90152fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(3.1)[7CBF1E7C-6810-3D0B-B5D2-49B649192B1F]@0xffffff7f924d1000->0xffffff7f9252ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f90dc2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f90124000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.7.21)[32B7E2DE-1F9D-3555-B687-7A76A62B81D2]@0xffffff7f92444000->0xffffff7f92457fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.7.21)[62689710-EEA7-307A-AC83-B8F25DA88A6A]@0xffffff7f9243c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f90dc2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f90124000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f903ec000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[0183904C-6A16-32C4-9405-EEFD7F820B02]@0xffffff7f9243f000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7f90449000->0xffffff7f906befff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f90124000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7f90433000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f903ec000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.7.21)[4700601D-3FEB-3B86-B2BA-8D71AF84D1C4]@0xffffff7f90443000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.0)[DC43029D-568A-3B7C-976B-E922C17F5143]@0xffffff7f906ca000->0xffffff7f90877fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7f90449000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f90124000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: SecurityAgent

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000000f600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800f800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800f700000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 10144085789
last loaded kext at 8810407586: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f91cef000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   901.19.10
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.1f2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B05, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Kernel panic (possibly device driver or hardware issue) is a tricky thing to debug. You should bring it to a Genius bar/Apple Store to have it debugged. You can see similar crash dumps in Apple Support Community but different issues/fixes.